# Need help with SOQL nested query

Tags: soql

How do I query a custom object record that matches following scenario.

Custom object has master detail relationship with Account. So I want to rerieve a custom record who's account matches with logged in user's--contact--account. I need it for lightning component so that I can use it on community.

is this achievable with SOQL?

Comment: What have you tried so far, share some SOQL which you had tried or thinking to use.

Comment: What is "User's--Contact--Account"? What are the relationships between those three objects?

Comment: @SebastianKessel User has standard lookup filed to contact and contact has standard lookup field to Account

Comment: @Rahul while I don't have completed query since not sure how to go down at the account level from user here is what I have been brain storming.. 'select name,status account from expense__c where account in(select name, contact from user ) '

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[User object](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_user.htm) has both AccountId and ContactId field populated for a community user.

Simplest query would be using a SOQL join as follows:

```
SELECT Id, Name, Status__c from Expense__c 
    WHERE 
    Account__c IN (SELECT AccountId FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId())
```

As I do not have custom object in my org, adding similar SOQL with standard object for reference which I have verified and works:

```
SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE 
    AccountId IN (SELECT AccountId FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId())
```

Comment: I did not suggest the "IN" alternative because it is less performant, but I agree that it would work just fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can do what you want in SoQL, but you're going to have to do that in two steps.

Because Acc->Conctact->User goes "down" in hierarchy and Custom ->Account goes "up", you won't be able to get them together in the same query.

Here is a way to do it:

```
Id accountId = [select Contact.AccountId from User where Id = :UserInfo.getUserID()].Contact.AccountId;

List<Custom__c> custObj = [select Id from Custom__c where Account__c = :accountId];
```

**UPDATE**

As Rahul suggested below

```
 List<Custom__c> custObj = [select Id 
                               from Custom__c
                               where Account__c in (SELECT Contact.AccountId 
                                    FROM User 
                                    WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId())];
```

should also work (did not get a chance to test it), though the IN clause makes the query less performant... which may not be a problem in your case.